# WPF application on Windows 7 responds normally only after pressing CTRL key

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am developing a WPF application using Windows 8 as developer machine with .NET 4.5. I have also used some DevExpress controls.

On the developer machine the application's UI responds normally.

When I test the application on Windows 7, either using virtual machines or other PC's, the UI is shown but it does not respond normally. For example, I have a DevExpress Grid Control, and when i click on a row the row isn't highlighted as selected, when the mouse hover buttons and menus, also nothing happens.

The magic begins when I press the CTRL key!
After that the WPF app responds normally, as it does on Windows 8.

I guess that when I press that key, something happens that has to do with Focus.
Also when the window is resized the changes on the grid appears, but after it 'freezes' again. Only by pressing CTRL the problem is gone.

Any ideas why that is happening?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you re-create the problem in a fresh WPF Project containing just that DevExpress grid control?

Comment: I will test it with a new project, thanks

Comment: With a new project from a DevExpress template, containing only a Ribbon and a Grid Control works fine...

Comment: it kinda sounds like something that has to do with running it on a virtual machine .

Comment: Not focus, probably keyboard state.  Have a look at the Keyboard.Modifiers property value.  How it could be wrong is impossible to guess.

Comment: The problem solved after removing a Windows Forms Host that was on the main window xaml file! Very strange behaviour btw...

Comment: Its a feature, not a bug.

Comment: It sounds like you were accidentally using a Winforms Application object instead of a WPF Application object.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behavior when creating WPF windows from a WinForms app. Fortunately, the Interop package also includes a method to work around this strangeness: `ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop`. After you make the WPF window, but before you call its Show method, do this:

```
public static void SetOwnerAndMakeTheKeyboardWork(this Window window, IntPtr ownerHandle)
{
    if (ownerHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        new WindowInteropHelper(window).Owner = ownerHandle;
    ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(window);
}
```